# Write a method to find the common elements between two BSTs, and insert them in 3rd BST

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I got an insert method and a search method, and I was thinking of a way to loop through the binary search tree and use a method like get nodes then search for it on the other binary search tree and if it comes true then I insert it that element, but the problem is I can't come up with a way to get the nodes based on index because its different than linkedList for example and can't think of a way to get the nodes to begin with; to sum up, I actually don't the proper way to start to solve that question.

```
public class BinarySearchTree extends BinaryTree {
    //default constructor
    //Postcondition: root = null;

    public BinarySearchTree() {
        super();
    }

    //copy constructor
    public BinarySearchTree(BinarySearchTree otherTree) {
        super(otherTree);
    }
public class BinaryTree {

    //Definition of the node
    protected class BinaryTreeNode {

        DataElement info;
        BinaryTreeNode llink;

        public DataElement getInfo() {
            return info;
        }

        public BinaryTreeNode getLlink() {
            return llink;
        }

        public BinaryTreeNode getRlink() {
            return rlink;
        }
        BinaryTreeNode rlink;
    }
    protected BinaryTreeNode root;

    //default constructor
    //Postcondition: root = null;
    public BinaryTree() {
        root = null;
    }

    //copy constructor
    public BinaryTree(BinaryTree otherTree) {
        if (otherTree.root == null) //otherTree is empty
        {
            root = null;
        } else {
            root = copy(otherTree.root);
        }
    }

    public BinaryTreeNode getRoot() {
        return root;
    }
public boolean search(DataElement searchItem) {
        BinaryTreeNode current;
        boolean found = false;

        current = root;
        while (current != null && !found) {
            if (current.info.equals(searchItem)) {
                found = true;
            } else if (current.info.compareTo(searchItem) > 0) {
                current = current.llink;
            } else {
                current = current.rlink;
            }
        }

        return found;
    }

    public int countEven() {

            return countEven(root);

    }
public void insert(DataElement insertItem) {
        BinaryTreeNode current;
        BinaryTreeNode trailCurrent = null;
        BinaryTreeNode newNode;
        newNode = new BinaryTreeNode();
        newNode.info = insertItem.getCopy();
        newNode.llink = null;
        newNode.rlink = null;
        if (root == null) {
            root = newNode;
        } else {
            current = root;
            while (current != null) {
                trailCurrent = current;
                if (current.info.equals(insertItem)) {
                    System.out.println("The insert item is already in" + "the list -- duplicates are" + "not allowed.");
                    return;
                } else if (current.info.compareTo(insertItem) > 0) {
                    current = current.llink;
                } else {
                    current = current.rlink;
                }
            }

            if (trailCurrent.info.compareTo(insertItem) > 0) {
                trailCurrent.llink = newNode;
            } else {
                trailCurrent.rlink = newNode;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the overall problem you are trying to solve?  Compute the union of the two binary trees?  Also, can you post at least the interfaces of the BSTs -- so we know what methods are available?

Comment: I'm trying to find the common elements between two binary search trees and insert them into another binarysearch tree as to codes I only have the insert and search methods.

Comment: If you only have search, you will either need to be able to enumerate all possible elements that _might_ be in the trees (and search for each one in both trees) or you are out of luck.  Are you sure there is no way to iterate through the elements already in the trees?

Comment: I wish I could use the iterator but I can't, yeah I'm outta ideas.

Comment: @hws you need to post something regarding your BSTs to get a better help.

Comment: I just did post everything regarding it if you need some more information feel free to ask.

Answer (score 1):

Traverse down to the left end of one tree, compare it with the root node of the other tree. If found equal, insert it into your third tree. If unequal, then check if it's less than or greater than the root of second tree. If less than, then traverse to the left child of the second tree and call your search method again, else, traverse to the right child of the second tree and call your search method again. Then repeat the whole process with the right node of the opposing starting node of first tree that you chose and call the search method again. Keep moving up the first tree as you repeat the process.

Here's a sample code(keeping in mind you have not provided any details about your trees whatsoever):

```
void search(Node node1, Node root2){
    if(root2 == null)
        return;
    if(node1.data == root2.data){
        //copy to your third tree
        return; 
    }
    else{
        if(node1.data < root2.data){
            root2 = root2.left;
            search(node1, root2);
        }
        else{
            root2 = root2.right;
            search(node1, root2);
        }
    }
}

void common(Node root1, Node root2){
    if(root1 != null){
        common(root1.left, root2);
        search(root1, root2);
        common(root1.right, root2);
    }
}
```

Comment: My understanding is the OP _cannot_ traverse the trees, only search for (known?) elements

Comment: @Attila I'm unable to understand what the OP has at his disposal to actually answer the question in the right way!

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you need to modify the `BinarySearchTree` class, so the following is written with that assumption.

You can traverse the tree by first calling `getRoot()` which will return the root of the tree (a `BinaryTreeNode`) then access the nodes' left and right children by calling `getLLink()` and `getRLink()`, respectively.  From each node you can get its value via `getInfo` that you can search for in the other tree (by calling the `search()` method on the second tree).

*Note*: as it is, you can only call methods on the nodes from within methods of `BinarySearchTree` as access to `BinaryTreeNode` is restricted to `BinaryTree` and classes deriving from it (for which `BinarySearchTree` qualifies)